# Не получается выйти из режима Debug в eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, отладка

Сори за тупой вопрос, но все же. Зашел в режим дебага и не могу из него выйти. Как это сделать?
При перезапуске проекта опять дебагер открывается.

Comment: Справа сверху нажмите `Java`.

Comment: Не нашел такого(

Comment: Eclipse neon.1 ide

Comment: Тогда попробуйте `Ctrl+F8`.

Comment: Огромнейшее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переключаться между перспективами можно с помощью <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Использование возможностей графического интерфейса (переключение перспектив):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers

Version: Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)
Build id: 20160218-0600